# Yum, Rpm and Find Command Not Found

Tags: debian, yum, rpm, vps, cpanel

I am trying to use "yum", "rpm" and "find" commands to install cpanel on my vps, but i am just getting "command not found", please help

Comment: Please, provide examples how you are using these commands

Comment: Judging by https://wiki.debian.org/HostingControlPanels you're basically SOL when it comes to trying to instal cPanel on debian, but there's a whole slew of available options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to tags you are using Debian distro. Debian uses apt package manager instead of yum. To update package list and install program run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install $your_package
```

To search package run:

```
apt-cache search $package
```

Use man pages to get to know more about that.

Also there is no rpm command but dpkg, since packages for Debian are *.deb not *.rpm.

Read these websites to find out more:
[Debian Packaging System](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/packaging-system.html)
[APT Tolls](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html)

Comment: Ok. Yum is package manager for RedHat-like distributions (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora). Debian uses apt package manager. There is no point to use yum in Debian. Read websites privided in my answer

Comment: According to [cPanel Install Guide](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Installation+Guide+-+System+Requirements) you cannot install cPanel in Debian. Frankly, I don't know much about cPanel, I don't want to tell you someting that is not true

Comment: I read before that apt doesn't replace Yum because Yum can take care of your packages ( updating them automatically ) while with apt you will need to run apt update yourself